# How do I ignore html attributes in Go using encoding/xml?

Tags: html, xml, go, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the body from any website's html, and it works if the html tag is just `<html>`, but if it includes any attributes (for example: `<html lang="en">`) then it doesn't pick up the fact that there's an html tag.

Is there any way I can get around this and make it ignore any attributes and see that there is still a tag there?

**note:** the reason I am using separate structs is for expandability later on as I improve and learn more about how Go and these libraries work

Here are the structs:

```golang
type html struct {
    Body body `xml:"body"`
}

type body struct {
    Content string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

Here is the method that prints everything

```golang
//ShowBody prints the body to console
func ShowBody(url string) {
    html := html{}

    xml.Unmarshal(GetHTTP(url), &html)
    fmt.Println(html.Body.Content)
}
```

The GetHTTP function uses ioutil and reads the page from an http call. The rest of the code is here if needed:
https://pastebin.com/rbxDLH2e

**expected:** prints the entire body into the console

**actual:** prints nothing, as it doesn't see the `<html>` due to the lang attribute

Comment: Why are you parsing HTML with the xml parser? Use the [x/net/html](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html) package.

Comment: Some of your code in the pastebin is ignoring errors, that's bad practice in Go. Then some other code is correctly checking for an error, if there is one it prints it, but then instead of exiting it proceeds to handle the primary value, which in case of an error would, in most instances be "invalid", and in this specific instance it would be `nil`, that's also bad practice in Go. When you get back an error, *do not* continue as if you didn't get back an error, that would defeat the whole purpose of errors.

Comment: rewrote the whole thing using the x/net/html package as Flimzy stated.
it all works now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want extract data from HTML file, you can take [htmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/htmlquery) to parse and extract data, like this:

```golang
doc,err:=htmlquery.LoadURL('http://www.example.com')
body:=htmlquery.FindOne(doc,"//body")
fmt.Println(htmlquery.OutputHTML(body,true))
```

The good thing is that it doesn't need any `Marshal` and `Unmarshal`, its very flexible.